# ggplot: change color of bars and not show all labels in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

I have not been working with r for long, but have already found many answers to my questions in this community. But now I can't get any further and ask my first own question.

Objective: I want to display values from different years (here in the example 10 years) over time in a barplot. Each year should be represented by a column. The years 1 to 9 should get a uniform color, the 10th year another. For the 10th year the value should also be displayed. There should be only two entries in the legend: "Year 1 - 9" and "Year 10".

I have created the following dummy data set:

```
 library(ggplot2)

# texts 2 display
tit <- "Title"
subtit <- "Subtitle"
lab <- c("lab1", "lab2", "lab3", "lab4")

# prepare dataset with random data
n_label <- length(lab)
cohort <-
  c(
    rep("year01", n_label),
    rep("year02", n_label),
    rep("year03", n_label),
    rep("year04", n_label),
    rep("year05", n_label),
    rep("year06", n_label),
    rep("year07", n_label),
    rep("year08", n_label),
    rep("year09", n_label),
    rep("year10", n_label)
  )
data_rel <- runif(40, min = 0, max = .5)
df_data <- data.frame(lab, cohort, data_rel)
df_data %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(cohort)) -> n_cohort
```

I was able to implement the plot as desired with the following code:

```
# plot data
df_data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar (aes(
    x = factor(lab, levels = c("lab1", "lab2", "lab3", "lab4")),
    y = data_rel,
    fill = cohort
  ),
  stat = "identity",
  position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                              size = 14,
                              face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = subset(df_data, cohort == "year10"),
    aes(
      x = lab,
      y = data_rel,
      label = paste0(sprintf("%.1f", data_rel * 100), "%")
    ),
    vjust = -1,
    hjust = -1.5,
    size = 3
  )  +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#7F7F7F", "#389DC3"),
    limits = c("year01", "year10"),
    labels = c("Year 1 - 9", "Year 10")
  ) +
  labs(
    subtitle = paste(subtit),
    title = str_wrap(tit, 45),
    x = "",
    y = "",
    fill = ""
  )
```

Unfortunately, I cannot adjust the colors of the columns for years 1 - 9. Either not all columns get the correct color, or I get unwanted entries in the legend.

Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong? I am grateful for every hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In setting the `fill` attribute you can group all other levels of the factor together (here using `forcats::fct_other` to collapse Years 1-9 into one level) to give your two levels of fill colours. At the same time, using `group = cohort` will keep bars separate:

```r
library(forcats)

# plot data
df_data %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar (aes(
    x = factor(lab, levels = c("lab1", "lab2", "lab3", "lab4")),
    y = data_rel,
    group = cohort,
    fill = fct_other(cohort, "year10", other_level = "year01")
  ),
  stat = "identity",
  position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,
                              size = 14,
                              face = "bold"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = subset(df_data, cohort == "year10"),
    aes(
      x = lab,
      y = data_rel,
      label = paste0(sprintf("%.1f", data_rel * 100), "%")
    ),
    vjust = -1,
    hjust = -1.5,
    size = 3
  )  +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("#7822CC", "#389DC3"),
    limits = c("year01", "year10"),
    labels = c("Year 1 - 9", "Year 10")
  ) +
  labs(
    subtitle = paste(subtit),
    title = str_wrap(tit, 45),
    x = "",
    y = "",
    fill = ""
  )
```

[image]

<sup>(Changed manual fill colour to distinguish from unfilled bars)</sup>

It's also possible to do by creating a new 2-level `cohort_lumped` variable before passing to `ggplot()`, but this way helps keep your data as consistent as possible up to the point of passing into graphing stages (and doesn't need extra columns storing essentially same information).